# Android Compose: Place an element in the center and other elements above it

Tags: android, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

I need to insert a Text element `Text("text center")` in the center of the screen (both horizontally and vertically). Also, I want to insert the `Text("text")` element above `Text("text center")` with a blank space of `32dp`:
[image]

So for example the following code is not correct because the whole block is centered and not just "text center":

```
 Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize(),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
) {
    Text(text = "text")
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(32.dp))
    Text(text = "text center")
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear I think

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/constraintlayout) since this type of layout would be a bit cumbersome to do properly with just the composables from the standard library.

> ConstraintLayout can help place composables relative to others on the screen, and is an alternative to using multiple nested Row, Column, Box and custom layout elements.

Add this to your `app.gradle` file

```
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.1"
```

and sync the project so that Gradle downloads the dependency.
As of July 2022 the stable version is `1.0.1`.

Your layout needs the following constraints:

1. the "center text" needs to center horizontally and vertically to the parent
2. the "top text" needs to center horizontally to the parent
3. there should be a margin of `32 dp` between the bottom of "top text" and the top of "center text"

In code these constraints are specified like this

```kotlin
ConstraintLayout(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize() // copied from your example  
) {
    // Create references for the composables to constrain
    val (topText, centerText) = createRefs()

    Text(
        text = "text",
        modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(topText) {
            // the "top text" needs to center horizontally to the parent
            centerHorizontallyTo(parent)
            // there should be a margin of 32 dp between the bottom
            // of "top text" and the top of "center text"
            bottom.linkTo(centerText.top, margin = 32.dp)
        }
    )

    Text(
        text = "text center",
        modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(centerText) {
            // the "center text" needs to center horizontally and
            // vertically to the parent
            centerHorizontallyTo(parent)
            centerVerticallyTo(parent)
        }
    )
}
```

Since the [official documentation on the compose version of `ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/constraintlayout) is really limited, you can check the [compose samples that are using it](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/search?q=ConstraintLayout) if you need more examples.

The official documentation for the Widget (non-compose) version of `ConstraintLayout` is good though, so to learn about everything that it can do, you can check https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout.

Maybe some of the functionality might not be available in the compose version yet. As of July 2022 the latest alpha version is `1.1.0-alpha03`

```
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.1.0-alpha03"
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in many ways.

Option one using a custom Layout

```
@Composable
private fun TextLayout(
    modifier: Modifier,
    padding: Dp = 32.dp,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    val paddingInPx = with(density) { padding.roundToPx() }

    Layout(modifier = modifier, content = content) { measurables, constraints ->

        require(measurables.size == 2)
        val placeables: List<Placeable> = measurables.map { measurable: Measurable ->
            measurable.measure(constraints.copy(minWidth = 0, minHeight = 0))
        }


        val topPlaceable = placeables.first()
        val centerPlaceable = placeables.last()
        val height = centerPlaceable.height

        val totalHeight = constraints.maxHeight
        val verticalCenter = (totalHeight - height)/2

        layout(constraints.minWidth, totalHeight) {
            centerPlaceable.placeRelative(0, verticalCenter)
            topPlaceable.placeRelative(0, verticalCenter - height - paddingInPx)
        }
    }
}
```

Option 2 Using a Box and getting height of text using onTextLayout callback of Text.

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxHeight()
        .border(3.dp, Color.Red),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart
) {


    val density = LocalDensity.current
    var textHeight by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }
    Text(
        "TextCenter",
        fontSize = 20.sp,
        onTextLayout = {
            textHeight = with(density) {
                it.size.height.toDp()
            }
        }
    )

    Text(
        text = "Text",
        modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 64.dp + textHeight * 2),
        color = Color.Blue,
        fontSize = 20.sp
    )
}
```

But this option, it's only for demonstration, will have another recomposition since we update `var textHeight by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }`

Option 3 is using a ConstraintLayout. For a simple layout that like this i don't think anyone counter any performance issues using `ConstraintLayout` but i always refrain using `ConstraintLayout` because it uses `MultiMeasureLayout` that comes with a serious warning

```
@Deprecated(
    "This API is unsafe for UI performance at scale - using it incorrectly will lead " +
        "to exponential performance issues. This API should be avoided whenever possible."
)
fun MultiMeasureLayout(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable @UiComposable () -> Unit,
    measurePolicy: MeasurePolicy
) {

}
```